# Show units not having values

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get all this information from computers in the Database, but some of the units do not have warranty information and is not selected. How do I get units without warranty information show up, with the other units?

```
SELECT Distinct A.[UNITID]
  ,A.[NAME]
  ,A.[DESCRIPTION]
  ,A.[UnitModel]
  ,Models.Model
  ,A.[FormFactor]
  ,A.[SerialNumber]
  ,A.[Manufacturer]
  ,A.[MACAddress]
  ,A.[IPAddress]
  ,I.[VALUE] as Memory
  ,Inv.[VALUE] as HDD_C
  ,INVType.VALUE As OSType
  ,C.[VALUE] as BiosDate
  ,WarrentyEnd.VALUE as WarrentyEnd
  ,WarrentyStart.VALUE as WarrentyStart
  ,WarrentyDescription.VALUE as WarrentyDescription
  FROM [DB].[vCAPApc] A, [DB].[Models] Models, [DB].[UNIT] Unit, [DB].[INV] I, [DB].[INV] Inv, [DB].[INV] INVType, [DB].[INV] Formfactor, [DB].[CSI] C, [DB].[CSI] WarrentyEnd, [DB].[CSI] WarrentyStart, [DB].[CSI] WarrentyDescription
  WHERE
  Models.ID = A.UnitModel
  AND Unit.UNITID = A.UNITID
  AND Inv.UNITID = A.UNITID
  AND I.UNITID = A.UNITID
  AND I.NAME Like 'Total M%'
  AND Inv.NAME = 'Drive C: Size'
  AND C.UNITID = A.UNITID
  AND C.NAME = 'Bios Date'
  AND INVType.NAME = 'Type'
  AND INVType.SECTION = 'Operating System'
  AND INVType.VALUE != 'Member Server'
  AND A.[FormFactor] != 'Virtual Machine'
  AND A.NAME != 'VAGTEN-2'
  AND WarrentyEnd.UNITID = A.UNITID
  AND WarrentyEnd.SECTION = 'Garanti'
  AND WarrentyEnd.NAME = 'Ophører'
  AND WarrentyStart.UNITID = A.UNITID
  AND WarrentyStart.SECTION = 'Garanti'
  AND WarrentyStart.NAME = 'Start'
  AND WarrentyDescription.UNITID = A.UNITID
  AND WarrentyDescription.SECTION = 'Garanti'
  AND WarrentyDescription.NAME = 'Beskrivelse'
```

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: ... and an explicit `JOIN` is very easy to convert to a `LEFT JOIN`...

Answer (score 0):

For fields which are null, try coalesce so that they satisfy your condition. Change the where query like this,

```
AND COALESCE(WarrentyEnd.UNITID,A.UNITID) = A.UNITID
AND COALESCE(WarrentyEnd.SECTION,'Garanti') = 'Garanti'
AND COALESCE(WarrentyEnd.NAME,'Ophører') = 'Ophører'
```

All warranty fields should follow this type null check to include in result set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Models.ID is not NULL. It is just not present in the t.able. Ex. A.Unitname is "Test" but "Test" is not present in Models. How do i get this unit?

Comment: Same approach brother. What is not present in model, use some formating to convert it to existing data.

Comment: I now have tried to use LEFT JOIN, not sure I did it right. I still do not get all rows. When removing Warranty part, i get all. `LEFT JOIN [CapaInstaller].[dbo].[CSI] WarrentyEnd ON WarrentyEnd.UNITID = A.UNITID
 LEFT JOIN [CapaInstaller].[dbo].[CSI] WarrentyStart ON WarrentyStart.UNITID = A.UNITID`

Comment: You should have clear understanding of JOIN, and the structure of your tables, unless I'm afraid you can't be helped!! If you want data with some condition and some of your rows doesn't met it, then use UNION operator to include that result set. I think that's the most I can do.